# Finding items that do not exist in a table from static values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a static list of strings from which I want to determine which of these strings do NOT exist in a particular table. This list contains over a thousand entries and do not exist in the database (and I cannot make changes to the database, I can only query against it)

For example, my list of strings could be `("Apple", "Orange", "Banana")` and the table I want to search against is:

```
Id   Name
1    Apple
2    Banana
```

The results of the query should be `Orange`
I can find the ones that do exist easily, but cant do the inverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your list to show up in the results, then you will need to construct a table of some type:  permanent, temporary, or derived.  For instance:

```
with list as (
      select 'Apple' as name union all select 'Banana' union all select 'Orange'
     )
select l.*
from list l
where not exists (select 1 from table t where t.name = l.name);
```

On the web, you can easily find a `split()` function, which would allow you to write a query such as:

```
with list(name) as (
      select *
      from dbo.split(@ListAsString, ',')
     )
select l.*
from list l
where not exists (select 1 from table t where t.name = l.name);
```

Here is another idea.  I don't really recommend it, but it might be applicable in some cases:

```
select @ListAsString = replace(@ListAsString, t.name, '')
from table t;
```

You would probably want to include appropriate delimiters.  The idea is to remove elements from the string.  In the end, you end up with a value of the non-matching names.  It is as a string, though, and not as a table.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE( Id INT, Name VARCHAR(20))

INSERT @tbl
    SELECT 1, 'Apple' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Banana'
```

Using `NOT IN`

```
SELECT Name FROM
    (SELECT 'Apple' Name UNION ALL
     SELECT 'Banana' UNION ALL
     SELECT 'Orange') t
WHERE Name NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM @tbl)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name from sometable 
where not exists (select 'Apple' union select 'Banana' union select 'Orange')
```

Is this what you are trying to do?